# How to make use of an accessor method of an object when that object is encapsulated within a const class?

Tags: c++, class, constants, operator-overloading, accessor

Let me pose the question more clearly.

I have a Datarow object:

```
 Class Datarow {
    private: 
      vector<string> vals;          

    public:

    std::string getVal(int index); //returns vals.at(index)
    };
```

I have a Section object that holds datarows:

```
 Class Section {
    private: 
      vector<Datarow> rows;          

    public:
      //Section methods
    };
```

And I Have an overloaded:

```
 inline friend std::ostream& Section::operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Section& sec)
 {

   for(auto& row : sec.rows) {
       if( sec.row.getVal(0) == "Tom" )  //<-- error here, c++ doesnt like me calling any method of 
           os << row << endl;       // "row", since sec is const
   }  

 }
```

Assume we have overloaded << operator for Datarow as well.  One solution may be not to use auto&, but it may be expensive to copy "row" each time if I have many rows.  I could not pass a const Section sec&, but that may be expensive as well. Is there an elegant solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to do this is make the necessary `Datarow` methods into `const` methods, like this:

```
std::string getVal(int index) const;
                          //  ^^^^^   add this
```

Now these methods can be called on a `const` object, as you are doing in `operator<<`.

Also, your `operator<<` is a `friend` function, and should not be qualified with `Section::`, like this:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Section& sec)
{
   // ...
}
```

Also, the `inline` keyword doesn't add anything useful here, so you can remove it.

Comment: That is embarrassingly fundamental. Thank you for your help cigien.

Comment: No worries, happy to help :) Also, consider accepting the answer if it ends up working for you.